# How to Parse Columns From Text Strings Using T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I used C# to extract text from a PDF file containing health care provider information and then dumped that data into a SQL table for staging but I'm having challenges parsing the data.

There are 6 columns total to parse out:
**[NPI],[Legal Name], [Service Address], [Effective Date], [End Date], [Comments]**

[End Date] and [Comments] columns are nullable so there may or may not be data in those two columns. I was able to parse out the [NPI] and [Legal Name] so far but not so much anything else yet.

Because of the way the PDF is rendered, sometimes information can fall to a 2nd or 3rd line if all the text doesn't fit on the first line of that record. When that occurs, I need to concatenate that fragmented record(s) with the last record of the sequence.

For example, for record #4 the value 'Only' should be concatenated with record #3 which should read as "Payment Suspension Only". This value is the [Comment] for that particular line. The entire line should look like this before actually getting parsed into columns:

```
1414141414 All Health Community Health Center 7300 Santa Clause Avenue, Huntington Beach, CA 90255 
7/5/2019 Payment Suspension Only
```

Another example, record #7 and #8 should be concatenated with record #6. So the entire line should look like this:

```
 1212131415 Desert Cities Midwifery dba Desert Cities Midwifery and Women's Health Care 1224 E 
 Wardlow Rd, Long Desert, CA 92881-7262 5/12/2021
```

Last example of this occurring is records 21,22,and 23. Record #22 and #23 need to be concatenated with record #21 so it should look like this:

```
 1877808933 SQUARE OF TRUST INC 5755 Mountain Road Room 222 & C106 & Nurse''s Office, Los 
 Angeles, CA 90028 12/20/2013
```

Here is the test data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#T') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #T
CREATE TABLE #T (ID INT,TXT VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT #T
SELECT '1', 'NPI Legal Name Service Address Effective Date End Date Comments' UNION
SELECT '2', '1003889502 Hachi, Vendog 1000 Bontpeliar Dr., Suite 9, Modesto, CA 95555-1216 5/11/2019' UNION
SELECT '3', '1414141414 All Health Community Health Center 7300 Santa Clause Avenue, Huntington Beach, CA 90255 7/5/2019 Payment Suspension' UNION
SELECT '4', 'Only' UNION
SELECT '5', '1515151515 Desert Cities Midwifery dba  Desert Side Birth Center Long 1224 E Wardlow Rd, Long Desert, CA 90807-4833 5/12/2021' UNION
SELECT '6', '1212131415 Desert Cities Midwifery dba Desert Cities Midwifery and Women''s' UNION
SELECT '7', 'Health Care' UNION
SELECT '8', '23141 Moulton Pkwy, 108, Laguna Hills, CA 92653-1241 5/12/2021' UNION
SELECT '9', '1467590901 Desert Cities Midwifery dba Desert Cities Midwifery and Women''s' UNION
SELECT '10',    'Health Care' UNION
SELECT '11',    '32326 Coast Hwy, Suite G, Laguna Desert, CA 92651-6700 5/12/2021' UNION
SELECT '12',    'Restricted ProvidersNPI Legal Name Service Address Effective Date End Date Comments' UNION
SELECT '13',    '1313131313 Desert Cities Midwifery dba Desert Cities Midwifery and Women''s' UNION
SELECT '14',    'Health Care' UNION
SELECT '15',    '1224 E Wardlow Rd, Long Desert, CA 92881-7262 5/12/2021' UNION
SELECT '16',    '1423596601 Desert Cities Midwifery dba Desert Cities Midwifery and Women''s' UNION
SELECT '17',    'Health Care' UNION
SELECT '18',    '1222 New Rascal Rd, Riverside, CA 92000-7262 5/12/2021' UNION
SELECT '19',    '1356331573 Desert Cities Midwifery dba Desertside Birth Center 23141 Moulton Parkway, Suite 208, Laguna Hills, Ca 92653-1241 5/12/2021' UNION
SELECT '20',    '1003206681 Desert Cities Midwifery dba Desertside Birth Center 1353 Old Temescal Rd, Suite 203, Corona, CA 92881-7262 5/12/2021' UNION
SELECT '21',    '1877808933 SQUARE OF TRUST INC 5755 Mountain Road Room 222 & C106 & Nurse''s Office, Los Angeles, CA' UNION
SELECT '22',    '90028' UNION
SELECT '23',    '12/20/2013' UNION
SELECT '24',    '1902223666 SQUARE OF TRUST INC 651 Glenwood Road Rooms 2101 & 2115, Glendale, CA 91202 12/20/2013' UNION
SELECT '25',    '1566664665 SQUARE OF TRUST INC 928 N Avenue 53 Room 1 & 3, Los Angeles, CA 90022 12/20/2013' 


SELECT * FROM #T
ORDER BY ID


SELECT 
 [NPI] = CASE WHEN TXT LIKE '%[0-9]%' THEN SUBSTRING(TXT,1,10) END
,[Legal Name] = CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(TXT,12,1) LIKE '%[A-Z]%' THEN SUBSTRING(TXT,-1+PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%',TXT),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', SUBSTRING(TXT,12,61))) END
,[Service Address] = ''
,[Effective Date] = ''
,[End Date] = ''
,[Comments] = ''
,*
FROM #T
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: If you already have a c# program, why not use c# to process the text data into the right structure *before* loading it into SQ:L?

Comment: Great question- I'm novice level at C# so that's why I'm attempting to process the data using SQL. If I had to use C# to process the data, where should I start? I'm also using SSIS so I would eventually need to figure out how to use script component right?

Comment: `SQL Server` is not good at parsing string. You should consider doing this at your `C#` application. Repost the question tag `C#` and ask in term of `C#` context.

Comment: From what you've said, it sounds like you have a fixed number of columns, always separated by commas. If there's no commas actually *in* the data, then the .net [string.split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0) method can separate each individual value into an array element, which you can then map to a column using the array index. Nothing complicated for you to do. If your data *does* contain commas then all bets are off, since there would seem to be no way to know what was a "real" field terminating comma.